# Add Angular website to an Existing wix site

Tags: angular, velo

I already have an existing application on Wix. Now, I have developed another website using Angular. Is there any way that I can integrate my Angular website with Wix ? like hosting my build files in their server ?

I tried WixCode but, they only allow writing js in their files. I couldn't upload anything. So, it will be really helpful if there is a way to integrate my Angular website with wix.

Comment: After reading this: https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-media-request-ftp-service I believe currently you can't do it.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too, currently I made a simple hack by attaching my angular website as an Iframe. But, yeah thanks for looking into this. :)